# 3 side by side boxes, toggle which ones show by dropdownlist

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/rnmk0zhz/5/

My JSFiddle is above

I have 3 drop down boxes, and below them are three divs which are hidden. When 'no' is selected I want the box directly under it to show.

I dont want it to always show on the left. I want the middle box under the middle dropdown list if no is selected in the middle, the other two to hide unless one of those are selected also. If the user selects 'no' in two boxes then I want two boxes to show.

I've tried floating them, but the padding is off when one hides and one shows. Absolute position wont work because there are rows of these and they'll overlap.

I hope I'm clear on what I'm trying to do here.

```
<table style="padding-left: 56px; padding-top: 3px;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 421px;">
            <div style="float: left; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" id="gray-select" class="gray">
                <select id="ddl1">
                    <option>yes</option>
                    <option>no</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 421px;">
            <div style="float: left; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" id="gray-select" class="gray">
                <select id="ddl2">
                    <option>yes</option>
                    <option>no</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 421px;">

            <div style="float: left; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" id="gray-select" class="gray">
                <select id="ddl3">
                    <option>yes</option>
                    <option>no</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div style="padding-left: 56px;" class="">
    <div class="box1" style="display:inline-block; height: 150px; width: 415px;">
        <span>box1</span>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <textarea style="height: 149px; width: 328px;"></textarea>

    </div>
    <div class="box2" style="display: inline-block; height: 150px; width: 409px;">
        <span>box2</span>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <textarea style="height: 149px; width: 328px;"></textarea>

    </div>
    <div class="box3" style="display:inline-block; height: 150px;  width: 409px;">
        <span>box3</span>
        <br/><br/>
        <textarea style="height: 149px;  width: 328px;"></textarea>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can simplify it to this using jquery toggle:

```js
$("[class^='box'").hide();

$("#ddl1").on("change", function() {
  $('.box1').toggle($(":selected", this).text() == "no");
});
$("#ddl2").on("change", function() {
  $('.box2').toggle($(":selected", this).text() == "no");
});
$("#ddl3").on("change", function() {
  $('.box3').toggle($(":selected", this).text() == "no");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="padding-left: 56px; padding-top: 3px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 421px;">
      <div style="float: left; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" id="gray-select" class="gray">
        <select id="ddl1">
          <option>yes</option>
          <option>no</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 421px;">
      <div style="float: left; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" id="gray-select" class="gray">
        <select id="ddl2">
          <option>yes</option>
          <option>no</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 421px;">
      <div style="float: left; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" id="gray-select" class="gray">
        <select id="ddl3">
          <option>yes</option>
          <option>no</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div style="padding-left: 56px;" class="">
  <div class="box1" style="display:inline-block; height: 150px; width: 415px;"> <span>box1</span>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <textarea style="height: 149px; width: 328px;"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="box2" style="display: inline-block; height: 150px; width: 409px;"> <span>box2</span>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <textarea style="height: 149px; width: 328px;"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="box3" style="display:inline-block; height: 150px;  width: 409px;"> <span>box3</span>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <textarea style="height: 149px;  width: 328px;"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

After your comment about the position of the boxes i suggest to use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`:

```js
$("[class^='box'").css("visibility", "hidden");

$("#ddl1").on("change", function() {
  $(":selected", this).text() == "no" ? $('.box1').css('visibility', 'visible') : $('.box1').css('visibility', 'hidden');

});
$("#ddl2").on("change", function() {
  $(":selected", this).text() == "no" ? $('.box2').css('visibility', 'visible') : $('.box2').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
$("#ddl3").on("change", function() {
  $(":selected", this).text() == "no" ? $('.box3').css('visibility', 'visible') : $('.box3').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="padding-left: 56px; padding-top: 3px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 421px;">
      <div style="float: left; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" id="gray-select" class="gray">
        <select id="ddl1">
          <option>yes</option>
          <option>no</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 421px;">
      <div style="float: left; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" id="gray-select" class="gray">
        <select id="ddl2">
          <option>yes</option>
          <option>no</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 421px;">
      <div style="float: left; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" id="gray-select" class="gray">
        <select id="ddl3">
          <option>yes</option>
          <option>no</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div style="padding-left: 56px;" class="">
  <div class="box1" style="display:inline-block; height: 150px; width: 415px;"> <span>box1</span>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <textarea style="height: 149px; width: 328px;"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="box2" style="display: inline-block; height: 150px; width: 409px;"> <span>box2</span>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <textarea style="height: 149px; width: 328px;"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="box3" style="display:inline-block; height: 150px;  width: 409px;"> <span>box3</span>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <textarea style="height: 149px;  width: 328px;"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it doesnt solve the box positioning when they become visible. This is more of a css issue, but I like what you did with the jquery toggle on text there.

Comment: uhh the problem wtih visibility instead of display none is that it's pushing all the other elements on my page down even when all boxes are hidden

Comment: The visibility CSS property has two purposes:

The hidden value hides an element but leaves space where it would have been.
The collapse value hides rows or columns of a table. It also collapses XUL elements.

Comment: crap, going to have to rethink this because it wont work,  I have 7 rows of these selects

Comment: No worries. If you have an url of your site post it and i will help you when i have some time :)

Comment: nope I sure don't it's in a c# master page in an undeployed site. JFiddle is really no different then anything I could upload at this point

Comment: I got it to work, had to set the height on the divs to collapse and  expand also

Answer (score 0):

Updating the answer after the change

Give a class say `.box` to the boxes and float it so that they are in one line. Also I have set width to the boxes as well as textarea giving `!important`. You should remove the inline widths of the textarea and the boxes and then remove this `!important`

```
.box {
  width: 25% !important;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
.box textarea {
    width: 100% !important; 
}
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/rnmk0zhz/6/)

Comment: thanks, that just got the jsfiddle running, click on the link above to see the new one. That's not the problem though, so this isn't an answer. The problem is the css on the box position. The left box should be under the left ddl, middle under the middle and right under the right.

Answer (score 0):

try the below sample, hope this will help you

```
.box1, .box2, .box3{
    visibility: hidden;
}
#wrapper{
    width:95%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rnmk0zhz/7/)